# Makefile bash & xargs variables doesn't work

Tags: bash, makefile

Here's a Makefile

```
roman@debian ~/D/O/devops> cat Makefile 
install:
        -cat projects.txt  | xargs -n 2 bash -c 'git clone $0 $1'
```

Here's projects.txt

```
roman@debian ~/D/O/devops> cat projects.txt
git@github.com:xxx/xxx1.git   app-xxx1
git@github.com:xxx/xxx2.git   app-xxx2
```

Here's what happens when I just copy this command to bash - it works:

```
roman@debian ~/D/O/devops> cat projects.txt  | xargs -n 2 bash -c 'git clone $0 $1'

fatal: destination path 'app-xxx1' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```

It's using git clone properly it's just repo exists.

Now when you do `make install` this fails, all variables are blank:

```
roman@debian ~/D/O/devops> make install 
cat projects.txt  | xargs -n 2 bash -c 'git clone  '
You must specify a repository to clone.
```

I'd like to use only xargs method in here, else it becomes too wordy, also there's even more problems when using loops. I've also tried to use `$(1)` but no luck

Comment: `make` is interpreting `$0` and `$1` as `make` variables and trying to expand them.  Try replacing `$` with `$$` -- so `'git clone $$0 $$1'`.

Comment: @G.M.THANK YOU, you can answer it in separate post I'll mark it as solved

Answer (score 7, accepted):

make is interpreting `$0` and `$1` as make variables and trying to expand them. Try replacing `$` with `$$`...

```
install:
        -cat projects.txt  | xargs -n 2 bash -c 'git clone $$0 $$1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `-I {}` to read lines and use that for the input inside `Makefile`

```
install:
    -cat projects.txt  | xargs -I '{}' git clone '{}'
```

Comment: What if arguments would be in different places?

Answer (score 0):

`make` expands dollar sign references to be its own variables. While it is usual to write `$(name)`, it is possible to write `$c` where `c` is a single character (as long as it is not a `$`), so when you use `$0` and `$1` in your command line, they will be substituted with whatever values those variables have inside `make`. (`make` does not know anything about bash quoting, so $-references will be expanded anywhere in the line.)

Since `make` does not automatically define `$0` and `$1` and it is unlikely that you have defined them in your makefile, the most likely is that they will be substituted with the empty string, resulting in the error you observe. To avoid this problem, escape the dollar signs by doubling them:

```
-cat projects.txt  | xargs -n 2 bash -c 'git clone $$0 $$1'
```

Having said that, it is not at all clear to me why you want to use `bash -c` here. What's wrong with

```
xargs -n2 git clone < projects.txt
```

Comment: Well I have use  case when I need variables in different places as a next task, so that I could run `docker-compose up $1 python manage.py test --settings=$2`

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me when I used two `$`.

```
$ cat Makefile
install:
    cat projects.txt | xargs -n 2 bash -c 'echo git clone $$0 $$1'
$ make install
cat projects.txt | xargs -n 2 bash -c 'echo git clone $0 $1'
git clone git@github.com:xxx/xxx1.git app-xxx1
git clone git@github.com:xxx/xxx2.git app-xxx2
```